# How to use CLIPS rule based engine in a linux environment

Tags: rhel, clips

I am new to computer science. My project requires to use CLIPS rule based engine and it runs in a RHEL box. Looking at the download link for clips
(http://sourceforge.net/projects/clipsrules/files/CLIPS/6.30/) there is no linux package available. I was wondering if this means I need to build it out of the source files to use it in RHEL?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

There are instructions in section 2 of the Advanced Programming Guide, http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/documentation/v630/apg.htm, for recompiling CLIPS on different platforms. The simplest way to create an executable is to place the core source code in a directory and compile it with a single line command:

```
gcc -o clips -DLINUX=1 *.c -lm
```

If you get any errors, try compiling with the GENERIC flag rather than LINUX:

```
gcc -o clips -DGENERIC=1 *.c -lm
```

Comment: Both commands are the same. How do you use the "GENERIC flag" ?

Comment: Edited the answer, changing LINUX to GENERIC in the 2nd command.

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal Fossa) you'll have to download and manually install the packages `libclips`, `clips-common`, and `clips` (in that order) from
https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/clips

Use the following command for each package file:

`$ sudo dpkg -i packagefilename`

Answer (score 0):

for ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get install clips
```

[image: CLIPS runtime in ubuntu]

Comment: for RHEL, maybe try $ sudo yum install clips

Comment: Hi, I cant install it. It said unable to locate clips, is there any solution for that? I am using Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

First you go into https://sourceforge.net/projects/clipsrules/files/CLIPS/6.40/

**Download the core file**, name : clips_core_source_640.tar.gz

Then unzip the folder,you will find a folder there named Core.

Go inside the folder,open terminal and run "make" command like this

```
make
```

Then you will be able to run clips with

```
./clips
```

*You can run clips only in the core file*

EDIT:

**I found out how you can run clips from everywhere,**

Go inside the core  folder and run:

```
sudo cp clips /usr/local/bin 
sudo cp libclips.a /usr/local/lib
sudo cp clips.h /usr/local/include
```

With this way you will be able just  to type clips and run it wherever you are.

[image]